# Active Directory password expiration in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I retrieve the password expiration, it shows a date 6 months after they changed their password, when it is actually set to 3 months. Is there a way to see this updated date? Or where is it being set at that I can pull that date in?

I currently am using this to output:

```
Get-ADUser -identity $ntaccount
@{ Name = "Expiration Date"; Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are expecting to find but this code works properly. Your code appears to be missing a couple of things. Namely your first line does not feed into the second and your are not returning the needed property from `Get-Aduser` which is `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed`

```
Get-ADUser -identity accountname -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | 
    select samaccountname,@{ Name = "Expiration Date"; Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

My account expires just under 42 days at the time of this post. My date is correct.

```
samaccountname Expiration Date     
-------------- ---------------     
myaccount      3/6/2015 11:34:29 AM
```

Are you expecting something else?

Comment: Take my work account for example: I change my password, it shows in powershell as expiration 6 months later. 90days go by and I get prompted to change. I was just wondering why the system is set to 90days but powershell is unable to pull that info?

Comment: @Aaron I would have to look into this further but if _active directory_ reports the date is 180 days then it should be considered correct. There are other ways to let an account expire and force to reset which may be happening. Do you have access to Group Policy to verify the account expiration settings assigned to your user? Is this behavior occurring with other users?

Comment: I should, can you refresh my memory on where to go to look? I'm new and trying to make this stuff for my own benefit. Also, yes, they enabled this 90day policy on other people, it's on purpose, I'm just confused why AD doesn't reflect on the changes.

Comment: @Aaron Easiest to start might be to run `gpresult /h c:\temp\result.html` then in that file you should look for the section about "Account Policies/Password Policy" that will have those details.

Comment: All I see when it mentions passwords is: Name: Default Domain Password Policy - Link Location: organizationhere.edu - Reason Denied: Empty . I went into Group Policy Management and looked there and it shows 180days...so something else is invoking 90days more specifically on each account but I have no idea where.

Comment: @Aaron at least you know now that PowerShell is not doing anything wrong. Since you can trigger password reset manually there is not much I can think to do to help you other than _someone_ knows how this is changed. Third party software maybe? Recurring scheduled task. I don't know.